# Get first non-empty string from a list in python

Tags: python, string, list

In Python I have a list of strings, some of which may be the empty string. What's the best way to get the first non-empty string?

Comment: Generated from regex: matches = re.findall(r"foo(\d+)|bar(\d+)") - I want the first non-empty string, but would be interested in how to remove all empty strings too (the regex might get longer).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
next(s for s in list_of_string if s)
```

Thanks to [Stephan202](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74939/stephan202) for this Python 3 version.

Comment: btw, it'll raise `StopIteration` if all strings are empty.

Comment: To avoid dealing with a `StopIteration`, the two-argument version of [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) can be used to specify a fallback value: `next((s for s in list_of_strings if s), 'not found')`

Answer (score 6):

To remove all empty strings,

`[s for s in list_of_strings if s]`

To get the first non-empty string, simply create this list and get the first element, or use the lazy method as suggested by wuub.

Comment: A bit inefficient, though! If you have one million non-empty stings after just an empty one, you'll spend time and memory generating a list of one million string, only to get the first one... At least, use  a generator!

Answer (score 4):

```
def get_nonempty(list_of_strings):
    for s in list_of_strings:
        if s:
            return s
```

Comment: Far less elegent than the Generator comprehension suggested above, also adds more complexity to the soruce file.

Comment: elegance in the eyes of the beholder, Daniel. It works flawlessly unlike the accepted answer's version: that's what matters

Answer (score 3):

Here's a short way:

```
filter(None, list_of_strings)[0]
```

EDIT:

Here's a slightly longer way that is better:

```
from itertools import ifilter
ifilter(None, list_of_strings).next()
```

Comment: Why is the second way better?

Comment: This only works in Python 2.x, and is less efficient than the generator example, because `filter` iterates over the whole list, irrespective of contents. In py3k `filter` returns a filter object, which is unsubscriptable.

Comment: @Fred:

The first way will go through and filter out every empty string, create a new list, and select the first result.

The second way will step through the list filtering out empty strings until it finds the first empty one and will return that.  No intermediate list would be created.

For example, if you have a list of 10,000 strings and only the first one is empty, the first method creates a new list of 9,999 strings in memory while the second does not.

Comment: @Stephan202: The "slightly longer way" is equivalent to the generator example, I think.

Comment: +1 for an answer that works in Python 2.x and 1.5.2 :-) -- unfortunately not in 3.x

Comment: @Steve. Indeed. The py3k equivalent is `next(filter(None, list_of_strings))`. (No import required.)

Answer (score 1):

to get the first non empty string in a list, you just have to loop over it and check if its not empty. that's all there is to it.

```
arr = ['','',2,"one"]
for i in arr:
    if i:
        print i
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I'll have to assume a lot, but to "get" the first non-empty string:

```
(i for i, s in enumerate(x) if s).next()
```

which returns its index in the list. The 'x' binding points to your list of strings.