# How do I get the last non-empty item in a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, generator

I just started learning Python today.

I have a list:

```
[text:u'Oranges', text:u'Apples', empty:'', empty:'']
```

How do I get the last non-empty item in a list? In this case, 'Apples'.

I see in [Get first non-empty string from a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138024/get-first-non-empty-string-from-a-list-in-python), they get the *first* non-empty value. Not sure how to get the last.

Comment: That's not a valid Python expression, much less a list.

Comment: I think he was just annotating it so we'd know what he meant by empty :)

Comment: Sorry it was actually a list of objects using xlrd.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
next(s for s in reversed(list_of_string) if s)
```

If you really have a dictionary, use `reversed(dictionary.values())`, but keep in mind that anything you do to the dictionary can change it's ordering, and it's not ordered in a consistent way between different versions of Python even for a given state.

Use an `OrderedDict` if you want the keys kept in insertion order.

Answer (score 6):

This:

```
d = [1, 2, 3, "", 4, "", 5, ""]
last_non_empty = [i for i in d if i][-1]
```